# Backbone subview not rendered properly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I started developping a website using backbone.js and after trying during the whole morning, i'm quite stuck on the following problem.

I output here only the relevant code.

I've a View called Navigator, that contains a Collection of Records (initially empty) :

```
var NavigatorView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/Navigator.ejs'],

    tagName: 'div',

    id: '',

    className: 'saiNavigator',

    events: {},

    initialize: function () {
        this.currentRecords = new RecordsCollection();
        this.currentRecords.on('reset', this.onRecordsCollectionReseted.bind(this));
    },
    onRecordsCollectionReseted: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var tplResult = this.template({
            computeTemplate: this.computeTemplate,
            records: this.currentRecords
        });
        this.$el.html(tplResult);
    },
    onDOMUpdated: function(){
        var me = this;
        var data = {
            device : 'web',
            gridId : this.model.get('gridId'),
            filterId : this.model.get('filterId')
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: App.getTokenedUrl() + '/task/getGridData.'+this.model.get('taskId')+'.action',
            success: me.onRecordReceived.bind(me),
            statusCode: {
                500: App.handleInternalError
            },
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: true,
            data : data,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    },
    onRecordReceived: function(result){
        var newRecords = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++){
            var newRecord = new RecordModel(result.items[i]);
            newRecords.push(newRecord);
        }            
        this.currentRecords.reset(newRecords);
    }
});
```

I've a View called dossier which html is

```
<div id="dossier1" class="dossier">
  <div id="dossier1-navContainer" class="navigatorContainer"/>   
  <div class="pagesNavigatorContainer"/>
  <div class="pagesContainer"/>
  <div class="readOnlyFiche"/>
</div>
```

When i first render the dossier (and i render it only once) i create the navigator in the following render function

```
render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
        uniqBaseId: this.id,
        className: this.className
    }));

    var nav = this.navigator = new NavigatorView({
        model : this.model,
        id: this.id+'navigator',
        el: $('#'+this.id+'-navContainer')
    });

    this.navigator.render();
    //We notify the navigator that it's ready. This will allow the nav to load records
        nav.onDOMUpdated();
    }
}
```

As we can see, i give the '#dossier1-navContainer' id to the navigator so that he renders there

So, here is how it works. When i render the dossier, it creates a navigator and inserts it in the DOM. When done, i notify the navigator that it can load its data from the server trough ajax request. When i receive the answer i reset the collection of data with the incoming record.

Juste before the this.$el.html(tplResult) in the navigator render function i output the resulting string.

First time it's

```
<div class="items"></div>
```

Second time when i get records, it's

```
<div class="items">
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
</div>
```

So the template generation is correct. However, when the second rendering occurs, the this.$el.html(tplResult) does **NOTHING**. If i look at the DOM in the browser **NOTHING CHANGED**

However if i replace this line by

```
$('#dossier1-navigator').html(tplResult)
```

it works. Which means that the first time, $('#dossier1-navigator') and this.$el are the same object, the second time not.

I've NO idea why it doesn't work the second time with the standard this.$el.

Help!!

Thanks in advance

Edit : after discussing a lot with Seebiscuit, i'm adding the few lines that helped answering the question

```
newTask.render();
var taskHtml = newTask.$el.html();
$('#mainTaskContainer').append(taskHtml);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless minutes of discussion with seebiscuit, we came up with the solution. The problem is all on the definition of the $el element. The formal definition defines it as

> A cached jQuery object for the view's element. A handy reference instead of re-wrapping the DOM element all the time

This is actually not very exact from a standard cache point of view. From my point of view at least the principle of a cache is to look for the value if it doesn't have it, and use it otherwise. However in this case this is NOT the case. As Seebiscuit told me,

> Because when you first bound this.$el = $(someelement) this.$el will always refer to the return of $(someelement) and not to $(someelement). When does the difference matter?
>   When the element is not in the DOM when you do the assignment

So actually, $el holds **the result** of the first lookup of the selector. Thus, if the first lookup misses then it won't succeed ever! Even if the element is added later.

My mistake here is to add the main dossierView into the DOM **after** rendering its NavigatorView subview. I could have found the solution if the $el was a real cache as the 2nd rendering in the ajax callback would have found the element. With the current way $el works i had just nothing.

Conclusion : make sure every part of your view is properly rendered in the DOM at the moment your try to render a subview.

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that your having a binding problem. I would suggest that you replace

```
 this.currentRecords.on('reset', this.onRecordsCollectionReseted.bind(this)); },
```

in your `initialize`, with:

```
this.listenTo(this.currentRecords, "reset", this.render);
```

No need to specially bind. Backbone's `listenTo` bids the callback to the Backbone object that sets the listener (the `this` in `this.listenTo`). Also has the added benefit that when you close the view (by calling `this.remove()`) it'll remove the listener, and help you avoid zombie views.

Try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm also thinking about a binding problem. I'll try your way and tell you

Comment: Nope, sorry not fixing my problem, however i think that indeed your way is better. The new problem now that i've put your code is that this.$el.html() doesn't render a single thing. It's like if my navigator creation wasn't working. Writing el: $('#'+this.id+'-navContainer') is correct right?

Comment: Wow. I totally missed that. `el` expects a selector, not a jQuery object. Pass in `el: '#'+this.id+'-navContainer'` without the jQuery wrapper

Comment: Scratch that. I just looked at the source. You are correct. You *can* pass in a jQUery object the way you do in your example. Backbone handles it correctly. I can't figure out your issue. Are you using a debugger, like Google Dev? Putting a breakpoint in your `.render()` function and watching the `this.$el` variable would be very instructive.

Comment: That the result after the first rendering : $el: jQuery.fn.init[0]
context: document
selector: "#dossierTask1-navContainer" and this is what the view contains : 
currentRecords: child
el: undefined. As we can see, after using $el, el is still non initialized.

Comment: and the div with this id exists!! <div id="dossierTask1-navContainer" class="navigatorContainer"></div>... haha ...  :-(

Comment: Ahh. Ok. That makes sense. `context:document` means that the selector (in your case `#dossierTask1-navContainer`) is not in the DOM. I thought about that possiblity, but I don't see how it gets removed...

Comment: Wait. Is there more than one element with this id?

Comment: wel.. i'm checking that at the moment, but the answer has and should be no!

Comment: The answer is indeed no. There is only 1 element with this id in the DOM. The strangest part of all this, is that if i write $('#dossierTask1-navContainer') it works. If i use this.$el which has #dossierTask1-navContainer as selector.. it doesn't... Oo woot?

Comment: Did you try setting `el: '#'+this.id+'-navContainer'`? Without the jQuery?

Comment: yep, tried both, same result.. this is madness...i just hardcoded the content of the selector of $el like this -> $('#dossierTask1-navContainer') and it worked... this $el SHOULD find my element...but it doesn't

Comment: Let's talk in the chat

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not using what your are passing to your navigatorView;

In your navigatorView try this:

```
initialize:function(el) {
    this.$el=el
    ...
}
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Sorry, doesn't help, the jquery definition of el/$el explains that $el is a cached version of el and there is no reason you use el directly. Like id, the el parameter given is already stored in the view without having to write this.$el=el

Comment: even if i don't have to write it in the initialize, there is something weird about it.. the solution might be around that el definition. I've been looking at tutorials and indeed the init is not used... but ...!